# Error while loading jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have jquery plugin jquery-1.4.2.min.js. while loading this file the following error is showing. but if i use it in another screen or another program it is loading successfully... i am unable to find the reason. Can any one help me please.
Thank you
Mihir
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not referencing (linking) jQuery more than once in the page and that the plug-in is referenced after the jQuery reference. What sometimes happens (especially with auto script management) is jQuery is loaded, the plug-in is loaded in the jQuery instance, then jQuery is loaded again, which effectively resets any plug ins.

Comment: thank you..but when i am trying to do the another simple application that same js file works fine. but in my code base it is not working... is there any dependencies may take effect?